# read a csv file in a zipped folder with R without unzipping

Tags: r, csv, zip

I have a zipped file named `master.zip` which contains 2 CSV files inside it: `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`

I want to read `file1.csv` only, something like: `read_csv('master/file1.csv')`, but without having to unzip `master.zip`.  How can I achieve this with R?

Comment: Can't you just unzip it to a tempfile? http://rstat.consulting/blog/temporary-dir-and-files-in-r/

Answer (score 11):

You just need to use the native function `unz()`. Let's assume that `master.zip` is in your working directory,

```
# just a list of files inside master.zip
master <- as.character(unzip("master.zip", list = TRUE)$Name)
# load the first file "file1.csv"
data <- read.csv(unz("master.zip", "file1.csv"), header = TRUE,
                 sep = ",")
```